# Why is PHP Cookie not set in cross-origin request by the chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that uses XMLHttpRequest to my host server. When I set a PHP cookie with XMLHttpRequest inside popup.js it is visible only in popup.js in next XMLHttpRequest. But when the extension is running on some internet page, background.js make XMLHttpRequest to my host server again but then the cookie is not visible. How do I make PHP cookies visible by all requests to that server?

PHP when setting a cookie:

```
setcookie("name","john", time() + 3600*24*1000, "/");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem. Cookie did not recognize the host domain. I followed again instructions from [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and then changed how I set a cookie to:

```
setcookie($cookie_name,$cookie_value, time() + 3600*24, "/","mydomain.com", 1);
```

This time i used variabels $cookie_name and $cookie_value but this had no effect to solution.

Answer (score 0):

Background, content and popup are independent and don't share state, including cookies. But you could communicate between them https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

So if you want to initialize your request inside popup then you have to pass the cookie to your background if you want to use it there.

Comment: I use a server of way communication between two. I don't need messaging. I managed to fix problem you can check it I added an answer.